# Save columns to text loop with filename loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling to figure out how to connect these two pieces of code that I've found together.

I have a sheet with c.400 columns that I want to save each column to a .txt file. The catch is that I need it to save the file using a name specified on another sheet (all in the order of the columns).

The two pieces of VBA I think are relevant are below;

```
Sub VBA_write_to_a_text_file_from_Excel_Range()
    Dim iCntr as Lonng
    Dim strFile_Path As String
    strFile_Path = "C:\temp\test.txt"

    Open strFile_Path For Output As #1
For iCntr = 1 To 10
    Write #1, Range("A" & iCntr)
Next iCntr
    Close #1
End Sub 

Sub CreateFolder()
Dim MyFile As String
MyFile = Sheets("Request form").Range("F9").Text
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sDir & "\" & MyFile
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Chris

Comment: Hey @CDH, welcome to SO! What error are you experiencing more specifically? What is the 'catch'?

Comment: Not clear? Say like this...1.What you require...2.What is your code...3.What is the problem with the code...! Post like that.

Comment: Hi @Klaster, I have a sheet with c.400 columns that I want to save each column to a .txt file. The catch is that I need it to save the file using a name specified on another sheet (all in the order of the columns). It needs two loops - one to save the columns and one to look for the names. I think. Apologies, I'm quite new to VBA.

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of the data in the "Request form" sheet including the Column Letter and first \ last row, and a small sample of the headers of the exported sheet (and its name)

Comment: Hi @paulbica, the file names start in A2 and goes to A791. There are 790 columns in 'Sheet2' that need saving individually as .txt files. Does this help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 ways to save columns to text files:

```
Option Explicit

Private fso As Variant

Sub saveColsToText()
    Const START_COL As Long = 2
    Const START_ROW As Long = 2
    Const FNAME_ROW As Long = 2
    Const F_PATH As String = "C:\Temp\"

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, thisCol As Range
    Dim lr As Long, lc As Long, i As Long, colStr As String

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With ws1
        lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = START_COL To lc
            Set thisCol = .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(lr, i))
            colStr = Join(Application.Transpose(thisCol.Value2), vbCrLf)
            saveColToFile1 F_PATH, ws2.Cells(FNAME_ROW, i).Value2 & ".txt", colStr
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub saveColToFile1(ByVal fPath As String, ByVal fName As String, ByVal colText As String)
    Dim fileID As Variant

    If Len(Dir(fPath)) = 0 Then MkDir fPath
    Set fileID = fso.CreateTextFile(fPath & fName, True)
    fileID.Write colText
    fileID.Close
    Set fileID = Nothing
End Sub

Sub saveColToFile2(ByVal fPath As String, ByVal fName As String, ByVal colText As String)
    Open fPath & fName For Output As #1
    Write #1, colText
    Close #1
End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```